# String matching with a specific character

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

The exercise I am trying to do is to basically recognize X, if there are a set number of Xs in string A then string B should also have a set number of Xs in the same position as string a but the problem I am having is that it's not recognizing the Xs and therefore string a cannot equal to string b, I don't quite understand my mistake in my code either so I would like to know the problem in what I am doing.

```
public class Excersize4 {
  
  public static boolean EqualX ( String strA, String strB )  {
    if ( strA.isEmpty() && strB.isEmpty()) {
      return true;  
    }
      
      else if ( strA.isEmpty() && !strB.isEmpty()) {
      if (strB.charAt(0) != 'X')
        return EqualX(strA,strB.substring(1));
      else 
        return false;
    }
      
    else if (strB.isEmpty() && !strA.isEmpty()) {
      if (strA.charAt(0) != 'X')
        return EqualX(strA.substring(1), strB);
      else 
        return false;
    }
      
    else {
      if (strA.charAt(0) == 'X' && strB.charAt(0) == 'X')
        return EqualX(strA.substring(1),strB.substring(1));
      else if (strA.charAt(0) == 'X' || strB.charAt(0) != 'X')
        return false;

      else if (strA.charAt(0) != 'X' || strB.charAt(0) != 'X')
        return EqualX (strA.substring(1), strB.substring(1));
      
      else
        return true;
    }
  }
  
  public static void main (String[] args)  {
    String strA = "XaXaXaX";    
    String strB = "XeXwXeX";
    
     if ( EqualX( strA, strB ) )
      System.out.println(  "\"" + strA + "\" == \"" + strB  + "\"");
    else
      System.out.println(  "\"" + strA + "\" != \"" + strB  + "\"");
  }
}
```

Comment: you could just use a loop and compare when the x appears

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code with a debugger, you will realize that the `if` conditions, in method `EqualX`, are wrong. They should be `&&` instead of `||`.

Here is the corrected code (which adheres to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)):

```java
public class Excersize4 {

    public static boolean equalX(String strA, String strB) {
        if (strA.isEmpty() && strB.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (strA.isEmpty() && !strB.isEmpty()) {
            if (strB.charAt(0) != 'X')
                return equalX(strA, strB.substring(1));
            else
                return false;
        }
        else if (strB.isEmpty() && !strA.isEmpty()) {
            if (strA.charAt(0) != 'X')
                return equalX(strA.substring(1), strB);
            else
                return false;
        }
        else {
            if (strA.charAt(0) == 'X' && strB.charAt(0) == 'X')
                return equalX(strA.substring(1), strB.substring(1));
            else if (strA.charAt(0) == 'X' && strB.charAt(0) != 'X') // CHANGE HERE
                return false;
            else if (strA.charAt(0) != 'X' && strB.charAt(0) != 'X') // CHANGE HERE
                return equalX(strA.substring(1), strB.substring(1));
            else
                return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strA = "XaXaXaX";
        String strB = "XeXwXeX";
        if (equalX(strA, strB))
            System.out.println("\"" + strA + "\" == \"" + strB + "\"");
        else
            System.out.println("\"" + strA + "\" != \"" + strB + "\"");
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, the following is printed:

```
"XaXaXaX" == "XeXwXeX"
```